# Is the analytical solution right?

Tags: qutip

This question requires the knowledge of [GRAPE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780704003696). More info can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kgrph09ghy5p74/khaneja2005GRAPE.pdf?dl=0) and in this short [presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huuhqwtvg1bx2ag/grape_june_2010_slides.pdf?dl=0).
In the following [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb) is the analytical solution as in this image right?
[image: anal-grape-qutip]
Because on trying (g = pi/ 4* T = 1/8) as in this figure 
[image: verify]
I am unable to get the U = cnot() (the target unitary)

I may have commited a mistake somewhere in the calculations. If so, I would be very much obliged if you would point it out to me.

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/issues/82)